# C# Main method decorated by a custom attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

I have met a strange thing when I decorate my Main method by a custom *Attribute* like this:

```
class Program
{
    [Attr]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main end..");
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class AttrAttribute : Attribute
{
    public AttrAttribute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Then the Console Program does not print anything. But when I debug the program, I find both the constructor of the attribute AttrAttribute and the Main method are indeed executed. Can anyone tell me the why..

And if I comment 'Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");' in the constructor of AttrAttribute, the program print "Main end.."..

Thank you every one.
(And sorry for my pool English.)

Comment: I just ran the same code, and basically the `AttrAttribute` constructor is being ran before the Console even exists. My guess is the console just won't exist until `Main`, the entry point of a console app, begins execution. What are you trying to accomplish with your attribute and why is it printing to the console?

Comment: It is the hosting process that's probing for the STA/MTAThread attribute.  Project + Properties, Debug tab, untick the option and it will stop.

Comment: Thank you, AdamVenezia, Dexters, Hans Passant. And the link @Dexters provided is very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the thing that is clear is that you have to understand that Attributes are created when the class' `Type` has `GetCustomAttributes()` called. With that being said, it kind of makes sense that your `Console.WriteLine` in the attribute's constructor is not shown -- you're program hasn't "officially" started yet because it hasn't entered `Main(...)`.

Now, when I ran the code and tested it, I found two things.

1. I get your issue when I run with the debugger. `Console.WriteLine` never writes to the console.
2. I **do not** get your issue when I run without the debugger.

When I run with the debugger and the Attribute's constructor hits, I can see in the debug screen for `Console` that it has all of the outputs/inputs being redirected. As I step through and enter `Main()`, the Console is still being redirected.

Commenting out the `Console.WriteLine` in the Attribute's constructor causes the `Console` to be reset once it enters `Main()`. This leads me to believe that calling Console.WriteLine before your program "officially" starts causes the console to get locked in place and not re-initialized.

Now this is part is just a guess, but I suspect that Visual Studio is capturing the `Console` in your applications instance for whatever it needs it for before it starts your application. Accessing it before, flags it to not reset/re-initialize.

Comment: Thank you. I just want to make sure that 'ctor of custom attribute will only be executed, when you will access it via reflection'. And now I get it. Thank you for your explanation.